# rspec output formatting in command prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, command-prompt

I am using rspec to do testing and it is giving me the following output. How can I fix the "←[32m"?[image: Output of rspec command.]

I get the same output while using Terminal in Aptana.

Comment: Just use an adequate shell (bash or zsh or similar). Those are usually not found on windows, however. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to disable colors in the RSpec output, or use a shell program that supports ANSI colors.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BUILDR-530

Comment: SuperUser link is broken.